# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() in beautifulsoup & selenium Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
i am trying to get these data from the website name Flipkart.com but i am facing error  i am using BeautifulSoup & selenium. i cant understand why this error is comming & i also tried many solutions available on internet.
```

is there any solution of i should try any other method for web **scraping** please help.

website is opening using selenium driver but unable to get data from the website and am not able to understand that why is this happening

```
here is my code which i am writing ans executing.

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product
ratings=[] #List to store rating of the product
content=driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRealme&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Realme")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

print(soup)

for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'bhgxx2 col-12-12'}):
  name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'}) 
  price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
  rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34'})
  products.append(name.text)
  prices.append(price.text)
  ratings.append(rating.text)
  print(rating.text)


df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices,'Rating':ratings})
print(df)
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

here is my error which i am getting from command.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MachineLearning\WebScraping\web.py", line 10, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 267, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: change `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(content.page_source, 'lxml')`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MachineLearning\WebScraping\web.py", line 10, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.page_source, 'lxml')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'  now this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `driver.get(url)` to load the page, you have to use `driver.page_source` to get the page source. `driver.get(url)` does not return anything.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRealme&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Realme")
print(driver.page_source)
```

One more issue with your code is that the class `bhgxx2 col-12-12` is used many times in that page. Some of them do not have a product inside it. This will give you an `AttributeError` inside your for loop.

A working version of your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
products = []  # List to store name of the product
prices = []  # List to store price of the product
ratings = []  # List to store rating of the product
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRealme&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Realme")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'bhgxx2 col-12-12'}):
    try:
        name = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'}) 
        price = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
        rating = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34'})
        products.append(name.text)
        prices.append(price.text)
        ratings.append(rating.text)
    except AttributeError:
        pass


df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': products, 'Price': prices, 'Rating': ratings})
print(df)
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Output

```
     Price                             Product Name  Rating
0    ₹5,999         Realme C2 (Diamond Black, 16 GB)    4.4
1    ₹5,999          Realme C2 (Diamond Blue, 16 GB)    4.4
2    ₹8,999           Realme 3 (Radiant Blue, 32 GB)    4.5
3    ₹8,999          Realme 3 (Dynamic Black, 32 GB)    4.5
4    ₹9,999          Realme 3 (Dynamic Black, 64 GB)    4.5
5   ₹10,999            Realme 3 (Diamond Red, 64 GB)    4.4
...
```

Comment: print(driver.page_source) this is printing the data. but  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml') is still showing error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MachineLearning\WebScraping\web.py", line 19, in <module>
    products.append(name.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @kartikchauhan See my edit with a working version of your code. Change to your appropriate chromedriver path.